# Call standard Python functions from cpdef function

Tags: cython

Given the following `test.pyx` file:

```
import os;

cpdef get_stat(filename):
    cdef os.stat_result stat_info

    stat_info=os.stat(filename)

    return stat_info
```

I cannot compile it with cython to analyze it:

```
Error compiling Cython file (`cython -a test.pyx`):
------------------------------------------------------------
...
import os;

cpdef get_stat(filename):
    cdef os.stat_result stat_info
    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test.pyx:4:9: 'os' is not a cimported module
```

Using `cimport os;` instead of `import os;` fails with:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cimport os;
   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test.pyx:1:8: 'os.pxd' not found
```

How do you get something this simple to compile with Cython?

Comment: Os.state_info isn’t a C struct/data-type but a normal python object.

Comment: Thus you would use `cdef object` or even better, no type declaration altogether

Answer (score 1):

As correctly pointed out by @ead, in order to interface with pure Python code, you have to use `cdef object` in the Python objects:

```
# test.pyx
import os;

cpdef get_stat(filename):
    cdef object stat_info

    stat_info=os.stat(filename)

    return stat_info
```

Testing it with a simple file:

```
get_stat('.vimrc')
#> os.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=45317471250423239, st_dev=920636878, \
#>   st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=1140, st_atime=1512123416, \
#>   st_mtime=1512123416, st_ctime=1500548526)
```